# Error handling servlet stopped working, and I don't know why :(

Tags: java, servlets, error-handling, wildfly

I'm working on a small MVC-project involving a couple of servlets and some jsp-pages. Early on in the project I added this ErrorHandler-servlet:

```html
package org.ics.ejb.lab;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/ErrorHandler")
public class ErrorHandler extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       

    public ErrorHandler() {
        super();
    }
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  processError(request, response);
 }

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  processError(request, response);
 }
 
 private void processError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

          Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request
                  .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
          Integer statusCode = (Integer) request
                  .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
          String servletName = (String) request
                  .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");
          if (servletName == null) {
              servletName = "Unknown";
          }
          String requestUri = (String) request
                  .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
          if (requestUri == null) {
              requestUri = "Unknown";
          }
          
            response.setContentType("text/html");
        
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.write("<html><head><title>Exception/Error Details</title></head><body>");
            if(statusCode != 500){
                out.write("<h3>Error Details</h3>");
                out.write("<strong>Status Code</strong>:"+statusCode+"<br>");
                out.write("<strong>Requested URI</strong>:"+requestUri);
            }else{
                out.write("<h3>Exception Details</h3>");
                out.write("<ul><li>Servlet Name:"+servletName+"</li>");
                out.write("<li>Exception Name:"+throwable.getClass().getName()+"</li>");
                out.write("<li>Requested URI:"+requestUri+"</li>");
                out.write("<li>Exception Message:"+throwable.getMessage()+"</li>");
                out.write("</ul>");
            }
            
            out.write("<p>Show Mats Svensson this error message. Then go back and try again.</p>");
           //out.write("<a href="index.html">Go back</a>");
            out.write("<br><br>");
            out.write("</body></html>");
      }
}
```

Then I added this to my web.xml file for the dynamic web-project:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>EmpClientProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
  </error-page>
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>JUnitEETestServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.junitee.servlet.JUnitEEServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JUnitEETestServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/TestServlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

It worked early on, but as I added some more content, html-pages, images etc the ErrorHandler-servlet suddenly stopped working and I haven't got a clue why. I can't think of any reasons why.

Here is the code that generetares a nullreferenceexception, assuming the employee doesn't exist in the database. The servlet used to catch this but doesnt anymore:

```js
package org.ics.ejb.lab;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import example.ejb.ics.Department;
import example.ejb.ics.Employee;
import examples.facade.ics.FacadeLocal;

@WebServlet("/EmpServlet")
public class EmpServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 @EJB
 FacadeLocal facade;
    public EmpServlet() {
        super();
    }

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  System.out.print("Error: Does not exist in database, try again");
 }
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  String url = null;
  String operation = request.getParameter("operation");
   
    if(operation.equals("showemployee")) {  
     String socialsn = request.getParameter("socialsn");
     Long pnr = Long.parseLong(socialsn);
     Employee e = facade.findBySocialSN(pnr);
     request.setAttribute("employee", e);
     url="/ShowEmployee.jsp";
    } else if(operation.equals("searchemployee")){
     url="/SearchEmployee.jsp";
    } else if(operation.equals("updatedept")){
     String depnr = request.getParameter("newdeptid"); 
     int intdepnr = Integer.parseInt(depnr);
     Department d = facade.findByDeptId(intdepnr);    
     String socialsn = request.getParameter("employeeSN");
     Long pnr = Long.parseLong(socialsn);
     Employee e = facade.findBySocialSN(pnr);

     e.setDepartment(d);
    
     Employee updatedEmployee = facade.updateEmployee(e);
     request.setAttribute("employee", updatedEmployee);
     request.setAttribute("department", d);
     url="/ShowEmployee.jsp";
    }
    else{
     url="/SearchEmployee.jsp";
    }
    
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);
 }
}
```